# How to query Active Tasks in TFS for only Active Epics

Tags: tfs

We are using Microsoft TFS in Azure for our agile project. For User Stories, we maintain a hierarchy of Epic -> Feature -> User Story -> Task. I am trying to write a Query using TFS query feature which will return all the Tasks which has State = "Active, New, Development, QA, Review, Closed". That's of course easy. Our problem is that we have loads of historical Epics and User Stories that were created long back but then State set as "Removed" as those were redundant. Unfortunately, those Epics had many User Stories and tasks created during those days which remains as State = Active. Cleaning those up is a job that is to be done later. But right now, my query should return only those tasks with the above State = "Active, New, Development, QA, Review, Closed" for which has a parent Epic with State = "New, Planned, Active". Is it possible to write one Query for this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the work items exactly following the hierarchy of `Epic -> Feature -> User Story -> Task`.

Then you can use `Tree of work items` query to get the active tasks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. With a little tweak, this worked wonders for me. Really appreciate the help.